# Java Program...Unexpected Errors

Tags: java

I am trying to compile this program which is available here,

> http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/breakout/

But I am getting errors,

The game consists of seven files.

Commons.java

```
package breakout;

public interface Commons {
    public static final int WIDTH = 300;
    public static final int HEIGTH = 400;
    public static final int BOTTOM = 390;
    public static final int PADDLE_RIGHT = 250;
    public static final int BALL_RIGHT = 280;
```

}

Sprite.java

```
package breakout;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Sprite {

    protected int x;
    protected int y;
    protected int width;
    protected int heigth;
    protected Image image;


    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return heigth;
    }

    Image getImage()
    {
      return image;
    }

    Rectangle getRect()
    {
      return new Rectangle(x, y, 
          image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null));
    }
}
```

Brick.java

```
package breakout;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;


public class Brick extends Sprite {

    String brickie = "../images/brickie.png";

    boolean destroyed;


    public Brick(int x, int y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;

      ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(brickie));
      image = ii.getImage();

      width = image.getWidth(null);
      heigth = image.getHeight(null);

      destroyed = false;
    }

    public boolean isDestroyed()
    {
      return destroyed;
    }

    public void setDestroyed(boolean destroyed)
    {
      this.destroyed = destroyed;
    }

}
```

Ball.java

```
package breakout;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;


public class Ball extends Sprite implements Commons {

   private int xdir;
   private int ydir;

   protected String ball = "../images/ball.png";

   public Ball() {

     xdir = 1;
     ydir = -1;

     ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(ball));
     image = ii.getImage();

     width = image.getWidth(null);
     heigth = image.getHeight(null);

     resetState();
    }


    public void move()
    {
      x += xdir;
      y += ydir;

      if (x == 0) {
        setXDir(1);
      }

      if (x == BALL_RIGHT) {
        setXDir(-1);
      }

      if (y == 0) {
        setYDir(1);
      }
    }

    public void resetState() 
    {
      x = 230;
      y = 355;
    }

    public void setXDir(int x)
    {
      xdir = x;
    }

    public void setYDir(int y)
    {
      ydir = y;
    }

    public int getYDir()
    {
      return ydir;
    }
}
```

Paddle.java

```
package breakout;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;


public class Paddle extends Sprite implements Commons {

    String paddle = "../images/paddle.png";

    int dx;

    public Paddle() {

        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(paddle));
        image = ii.getImage();

        width = image.getWidth(null);
        heigth = image.getHeight(null);

        resetState();

    }

    public void move() {
        x += dx;
        if (x <= 2) 
          x = 2;
        if (x >= Commons.PADDLE_RIGHT)
          x = Commons.PADDLE_RIGHT;
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            dx = -2;

        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            dx = 2;
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            dx = 0;
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            dx = 0;
        }
    }

    public void resetState() {
        x = 200;
        y = 360;
    }
}
```

Board.java

```
package breakout;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Board extends JPanel implements Commons {

    Image ii;
    Timer timer;
    String message = "Game Over";
    Ball ball;
    Paddle paddle;
    Brick bricks[];

    boolean ingame = true;
    int timerId;


    public Board() {

        addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
        setFocusable(true);

        bricks = new Brick[30];
        setDoubleBuffered(true);
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ScheduleTask(), 1000, 10);
    }

        public void addNotify() {
            super.addNotify();
            gameInit();
        }

    public void gameInit() {

        ball = new Ball();
        paddle = new Paddle();


        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                bricks[k] = new Brick(j * 40 + 30, i * 10 + 50);
                k++;
            }
        }
    }


    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

        if (ingame) {
            g.drawImage(ball.getImage(), ball.getX(), ball.getY(),
                        ball.getWidth(), ball.getHeight(), this);
            g.drawImage(paddle.getImage(), paddle.getX(), paddle.getY(),
                        paddle.getWidth(), paddle.getHeight(), this);

            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                if (!bricks[i].isDestroyed())
                    g.drawImage(bricks[i].getImage(), bricks[i].getX(),
                                bricks[i].getY(), bricks[i].getWidth(),
                                bricks[i].getHeight(), this);
            }
        } else {

            Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 18);
            FontMetrics metr = this.getFontMetrics(font);

            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.setFont(font);
            g.drawString(message,
                         (Commons.WIDTH - metr.stringWidth(message)) / 2,
                         Commons.WIDTH / 2);
        }


        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        g.dispose();
    }

    private class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            paddle.keyReleased(e);
        }

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            paddle.keyPressed(e);
        }
    }


    class ScheduleTask extends TimerTask {

        public void run() {

            ball.move();
            paddle.move();
            checkCollision();
            repaint();

        }
    }

    public void stopGame() {
        ingame = false;
        timer.cancel();
    }


    public void checkCollision() {

        if (ball.getRect().getMaxY() > Commons.BOTTOM) {
            stopGame();
        }

        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            if (bricks[i].isDestroyed()) {
                j++;
            }
            if (j == 30) {
                message = "Victory";
                stopGame();
            }
        }

        if ((ball.getRect()).intersects(paddle.getRect())) {

            int paddleLPos = (int)paddle.getRect().getMinX();
            int ballLPos = (int)ball.getRect().getMinX();

            int first = paddleLPos + 8;
            int second = paddleLPos + 16;
            int third = paddleLPos + 24;
            int fourth = paddleLPos + 32;

            if (ballLPos < first) {
                ball.setXDir(-1);
                ball.setYDir(-1);
            }

            if (ballLPos >= first && ballLPos < second) {
                ball.setXDir(-1);
                ball.setYDir(-1 * ball.getYDir());
            }

            if (ballLPos >= second && ballLPos < third) {
                ball.setXDir(0);
                ball.setYDir(-1);
            }

            if (ballLPos >= third && ballLPos < fourth) {
                ball.setXDir(1);
                ball.setYDir(-1 * ball.getYDir());
            }

            if (ballLPos > fourth) {
                ball.setXDir(1);
                ball.setYDir(-1);
            }


        }


        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            if ((ball.getRect()).intersects(bricks[i].getRect())) {

                int ballLeft = (int)ball.getRect().getMinX();
                int ballHeight = (int)ball.getRect().getHeight();
                int ballWidth = (int)ball.getRect().getWidth();
                int ballTop = (int)ball.getRect().getMinY();

                Point pointRight =
                    new Point(ballLeft + ballWidth + 1, ballTop);
                Point pointLeft = new Point(ballLeft - 1, ballTop);
                Point pointTop = new Point(ballLeft, ballTop - 1);
                Point pointBottom =
                    new Point(ballLeft, ballTop + ballHeight + 1);

                if (!bricks[i].isDestroyed()) {
                    if (bricks[i].getRect().contains(pointRight)) {
                        ball.setXDir(-1);
                    }

                    else if (bricks[i].getRect().contains(pointLeft)) {
                        ball.setXDir(1);
                    }

                    if (bricks[i].getRect().contains(pointTop)) {
                        ball.setYDir(1);
                    }

                    else if (bricks[i].getRect().contains(pointBottom)) {
                        ball.setYDir(-1);
                    }

                    bricks[i].setDestroyed(true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the Final,

Breakout.java

```
package breakout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Breakout extends JFrame {

    public Breakout()
    {
        add(new Board());
        setTitle("Breakout");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(Commons.WIDTH, Commons.HEIGTH);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Breakout();
    }
}
```

But I am getting these errors,

```
C:\jdk1.3.0_02\bin>javac Breakout.java
Breakout.java:9: cannot resolve symbol
symbol  : class Board
location: class breakout.Breakout
        add(new Board());
                ^
Breakout.java:12: cannot resolve symbol
symbol  : variable Commons
location: class breakout.Breakout
        setSize(Commons.WIDTH, Commons.HEIGTH);
                ^
Breakout.java:12: cannot resolve symbol
symbol  : variable Commons
location: class breakout.Breakout
        setSize(Commons.WIDTH, Commons.HEIGTH);
                               ^
Breakout.java:13: cannot resolve symbol
symbol  : method setLocationRelativeTo  (<null>)
location: class breakout.Breakout
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        ^
Breakout.java:14: cannot resolve symbol
symbol  : method setIgnoreRepaint  (boolean)
location: class breakout.Breakout
        setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        ^
5 errors

C:\jdk1.3.0_02\bin>
```

I do not understand what is causing the issue, since I haven't made any changes in the original code.

Comment: how do you compile? using javac? or using an ide like eclipse? Your issue is definitely because you haven't put the .java files inside your classpath. The simpler way is to import the project in ide in Eclipse/netbeans/ some other ide.

Comment: For your own sanity, I seriously suggest you get hold of an IDE

Comment: @ruby Take a look at the output `C:\jdk1.3.0_02\bin>javac Breakout.java` - it's easy to miss in all the noise

Comment: nothing more to add, than stop following that kind of tutorials and try to loose coupling from that code, omg! xD

Comment: You give far too much information Xufyan. That's better than giving not enough, but you should still try to give only relevant information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you run the Breakout.java but The compiler does not know that it has also need to consider to compile Broad.java and other files.

You have 2 options to solve this :

1. Download IDE to make it easier to add the classpath. **( Recommended )**
   You can install [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-standard-431/keplersr1) / Netbeans / other IDE and import all the java files to a project and run the Breakout.java.
2. Run the javac with -sourcepath parameter.
   This is not straightforward. but you better take a look at [javac command documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html).

   Example :

   javac -d C:\projectsCC\ETL\xtract\adm\common\classes -sourcepath C:\projectsCC\ETL\xtract\adm\common\src C:\ibm\esmrt\adm\common\Conductor.java

> -sourcepath sourcepath Specify the source code path to search for class or interface definitions. As with the user class path, source
>   path entries are separated by semicolons (;) and can be directories,
>   JAR archives, or ZIP archives. If packages are used, the local path
>   name within the directory or archive must reflect the package name.
>   Note: Classes found through the class path may be subject to automatic
>   recompilation if their sources are also found. See Searching For
>   Types.

Comment: What should the OP specify with the -cp argument?

Comment: I mean, since the files are in the current directory, and since when -cp is not specified, the current directory is in the classpath, I don't see how your answer address the problem.

Comment: @EtienneMiret, it should be -sourcepath ( and not classpath ).

Comment: Indeed, I mistake classpath for sourcepath. But still, the default sourcepath is the current directory.

Answer (score -1):

This is because your java files are not in a "breakout" directory.

You need to put them in such a directory, then compile them from outside said directory:

```
C:\jdk1.3.0_02\bin>javac breakout\Breakout.java
```